systemd user service: environmental variables not loaded at startup but loaded when restarting service
I run emacs as a service, using the following systemd config file:
[Unit] 
Description=Emacs text editor 
Documentation=info:emacs man:emacs(1) https://gnu.org/software/emacs/ 
After=graphical-session.target
 
[Service] 
Type=forking 
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/emacs --daemon 
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/emacsclient --eval "(kill-emacs)" 
Environment=SSH_AUTH_SOCK=%t/keyring/ssh 
EnvironmentFile=/some-path/systemd/emacs.env
PassEnvironment=BIBINPUTS BSTINPUTS TEXINPUTS LANG SHELL PATH
Restart=on-failure 

[Install] 
WantedBy=default.target

The emacs.env file contains the following definitions:
BIBINPUTS=.:/xxx/Jabref/:
BSTINPUTS=.:/xxx/LaTeX/bibstyles//:
TEXINPUTS=.:/xxx/LaTeX//:
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SHELL=/usr/local/bin/fish

The strange thing is that after booting my computer, the service runs:
 ~> systemctl --user status emacs
● emacs.service - Emacs text editor
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/local/lib/systemd/user/emacs.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2024-10-08 13:19:57 CEST; 11s ago
       Docs: info:emacs
             man:emacs(1)
             https://gnu.org/software/emacs/
   Main PID: 1785 (emacs)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 37288)
     Memory: 263.0M
        CPU: 1.404s
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/emacs.service
             ├─1785 /usr/local/bin/emacs --fg-daemon
             └─2441 /usr/bin/aspell -a -m -B --encoding=utf-8

Oct 08 13:19:57 xxx emacs[1785]: Starting Emacs daemon.
Oct 08 13:19:57 xxx systemd[1776]: Started Emacs text editor.

But when I start emacs using emacsclient -no-wait --create-frame and inspect the environment using M-x getenv, the environmental variables in emacs.env are not set.
Once I restart the emacs service using
~> systemctl --user restart emacs
~> systemctl --user status emacs
● emacs.service - Emacs text editor
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/local/lib/systemd/user/emacs.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2024-10-08 13:25:08 CEST; 4s ago
       Docs: info:emacs
             man:emacs(1)
             https://gnu.org/software/emacs/
   Main PID: 36413 (emacs)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 37288)
     Memory: 83.3M
        CPU: 1.147s
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/emacs.service
             ├─36413 /usr/local/bin/emacs --fg-daemon
             └─36727 /usr/bin/aspell -a -m -B --encoding=utf-8

and then run the emacs client as before
~> emacsclient -no-wait --create-frame

the environmental variables are exported as they should.
Why aren't these environmental variables loaded at startup? I also checked syslog but could not find any error message or hint.

Where is /some-path actually? Is it on the root filesystem or a separate local filesystem or an encrypted volume or a USB stick or a network filesystem?

@grawity /some/path is on a disk mounted directly at boot time (in /etc/fstab)

Is it a nofail fstab entry?

man systemd.exec says that you should get an error or warning if the file in EnvironmentFile= does not exist, so if you aren't seeing one, this aspect of the Unit must be ok. PassEnvironment= does not seem pertinent, and might have some side-effect; try removing it.

PassEnvironment was needed, otherwise the variables were not set, despite being in the file. The fstab is not a nofail, and I see in syslog that it is mounted very early on, and later there is a message Starting Emacs text editor. with no error that follows.
